# glColorPointer() not painting vertex color in interleaved VBO

Tags: python, opengl, shader, vbo, pyopengl

I am using (Python and PyOpenGL) interleaved VBO (vertex, normal, color) in the form:

```
Vx1, Vy1, Vz1, Nx1, Ny1, Nz1, R1, G1, B1, A1, Vx2...
```

VBO is generated with:

```
self.vbo_id = glGenBuffers (1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)

#    upload data to VBO
data = model_loader.Model_loader(filename = "geometry.STL")  
self.N_vertices = len(vertices)

alpha = 1
color = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, alpha]], dtype='float32')
colors = np.repeat(color, self.N_vertices, axis=0)

VBO_data = VBO_reshape.create_VBO_array(data.vertices, data.normals, colors, GL_primitive_type = "triangle", interleaved_type = "true")
VBO_size_bytes = arrays.ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(VBO_data)

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_size_bytes, VBO_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)
```

Geometry from VBO is drawn with the code:

```
v_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(0)
n_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(12)  
c_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(24)

v_stride = 40
n_stride = 40
c_stride = 40

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)
# enable vertex array
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, v_stride, v_pointer)

# enable normal array 
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, n_stride, n_pointer)

# enable color array 
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, c_stride, c_pointer)

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, self.N_vertices)

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) # reset

glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```

The geometry (vertices and normals) are drawn correctly (see figure below). I want to paint each vertex with different color but is not painting any colors? Any suggestions how to draw color of vertex with `GL_TRIANGLES` and calls to `gl_DrawArrays()` and `glColorPointer`? Do I have to use shaders or can this be done without shaders? If I understand correctly it can be done without using shaders.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The solution was to disable lighting and lights. But there is a new one. If I disable lights and lighting a model is painted in uniform color it looks like that normals are not used when drawing.

- Left cube: vertex colors and lighting (and lights) disabled
- Center cube: vertex colors are not shown, because lighting (and) lights are enabled
- Right cube: uniform color of vertices and lighting (and lights) disabled

[image]

I would like to draw the center cube but with (uniform) color as the right cube. I would like to ask you how can this be achieved? I use interleaved VBO. Thanks for suggestions, as right now I am without them :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, and what you posted isn't directly an answer, because you're asking a new question in the answer. An answer should be AN ANSWER, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I suggest you read up on the [SO community guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  Anyway client-side arrays, built-in array attributes, and fixed-function shading are all deprecated, and FYI, the only cube above with uniform color is the one on the right.  Different shades of the same hue are not the same color.  I suspect what you are looking for, however is `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`.